# extending ASP.NET Page using MasterPage attributes as properties

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have an authentication roles-based system: different roles are redirected to different folders and in each folder there is a web.config that allows the access only to a particular username.

Few roles have the default page in common with a gridview that react in different ways depending on the role(different columns are shown, events trigger different methods, etc.).

so my problem is that everytime I need to make minor changes to a page I need to copy/paste the same changes to all the others default pages in the other folders.

In terms of code I solved by creating a DefaultFather class which extends System.Web.UI.Page and every other Default class inherits from DefaultFather. In this way, if I dont declare a Page-life-method, the DefaultFather method will be triggered.

but what about the graphic part(html, javascript, asp components, etc...)??

I created a NestedMasterPage just for the Default pages but everytime I need to change the appearance/behaviour of controls(gridview, buttons, linkbuttons) I must use the FindControl() method.

there isnt really another way to solve this problem?
Im thinking of using the Page_Load() method to search for each control with FindControl() and save them into attributes for later usage but it doesnt really look like a good solution.
It would be nice if I could use the masterpage components as properties but I think that in order to do that I should create public properties and I dont know if it will cause some kind of security problem.

any suggestion?

btw, if masterpage is the solution, should I remove the DefaultFather class and place the code directly into the masterpage? or is it a good idea to have another class just for the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there's nothing wrong with having both a master page and a base class for your page. They serve different purposes. The master page is generally all about layout, and the base class would be about page functionality.

If you want to manipulate the markup on your master page, rather than accessing the fields directly, I'd say create a logical function which does what you need it to do, and let the master page do it.

```
// Site.Master.cs
public void HideSubmitButton()
{
    btnSubmit.Visible = false;
}

// Default.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((SiteMaster)Master).HideSubmitButton();
}
```

I'd probably wrap that cast so you can use it more easily - that is something that would belong in your base class:

```
// DefaultFather.cs
protected new SiteMaster Master { get { return (SiteMaster)base.Master; } }

// Default.aspx.cs
Master.HideSubmitButton();
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment about attaching event handlers - if you need to attach events to objects that live on the master (which may not be a good idea - ideally the event handler for something living on the master lives on the master - but if you really need it) you can expose methods to do that as well, like:

```
// Site.Master.cs
public void AttachEventHandlerToGoButton(EventHandler eventHandler)
{
    btnGo.Click += eventHandler;
}

// Default.aspx.cs
Master.AttachEventHandlerToGoButton(DoMyThing);

private void DoMyThing(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

or if you want to get fancy, write a wrapper event:

```
// Site.Master
<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />

// Site.Master.cs
public event EventHandler GoButtonClick;

protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (GoButtonClick != null) {
        GoButtonClick(sender, e);
    }
}

// Default.aspx.cs
Master.GoButtonClick += DoMyThing;

private void DoMyThing(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Also see my edit on the Master wrapper - you need the `base.` there to avoid a stack overflow.

Comment: interesting, what about the events? how do I respond to an OnClick event of example?

Comment: can't I just declare: private SiteMaster master; and inizialize it on Page_Init() in the default class? It seems easier to me than using new that may cause problem.     and a last thing if I may...  so right now I have a Master file and a base DefaultFather class, and others Default classes that extends DefaultFather. is it too much if I ask an example on how handling an OnClick() event that should act differently based on the different default.aspx?

Comment: Sure, a separate field or property for the `Master` wrapper would work just fine, it's just a preference thing. But don't be afraid of using `new` - it's a little uncommon, but it does work without issue as long as you use it right.

Comment: For the `OnClick` thing, my bottom two examples show how to do this. Your button lives in the master page, but the master page doesn't do anything upon click, but rather just exposes a way to attach events to it. Your page can attach whatever event handler it wants - in my example the `DoMyThing` method, which lives in the page code-behind, gets attached to the master page's btnGo, even though the page doesn't know anything about the button itself. Each page can attach whatever handler it wants here.

Comment: thanks mate! I followed your advice and now it's all beautifull and working perfectly :)